# Download Manager/Accelerator for Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, download-manager

I'm looking for a download manager that has the following characteristics:

1. Must support multiple downloads at the same time
2. Resume support
3. Multipart support
4. Integration with Chrome/ium and Firefox (preferable but not required)
5. Must be standalone (aka no browser/virtual machine dependant)
6. Shouldn't have fremium characteristics
7. Must have a deb package ready to install (if it's via official repositories better)
8. Should be configurable on the number of connections per server and globally
9. Rate limit and schedule

Answer (score 9):

I'm using [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/).  uGet is quite powerful download manager which uses [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) protocol to accelerate downloads. Aria2 is a command line download utility supporting multi-source and  multi-protocol downloads. uGet is a standalone downloader running on Linux and Windows.

[image: uGet main screen]

**As requested**

- **Must support multiple downloads at the same time** - configurable how
  many downloads  you want active.
- **Resume support** - yes with or without aria2 plug-in
- **Multipart support** - yes configurable how many parts too
- **Integration with Chrome/ium and Firefox (preferable but not required)** -  yes, clipboard monitor where you can set which
  extension to be added    to download manager. Chrome/mium extension
  available & Firefox Integration is arranged via FlashGot add-on
- **Must be standalone (aka no browser/virtual machine dependant)** yes standalone & works with Linux & Windows
- **Shouldn't have fremium characteristics** - not sure what you mean,
  however there is no free/paid versions  but only free
- **Must have a deb package ready to install (if it's via official

  repositories better)** - uGet is included in Ubuntu repositories  but not up to-date  so it's better to download [deb](http://ugetdm.com/downloads) from their site. PPA and RPM
  available too.
- **Should be configurable on the number of connections per server and

  globally Rate limit and schedule** - uGet comes with scheduler,
  connections can be limited for all downloads or specific downloads.

List of features available [here](http://ugetdm.com/features)

[image: aria2 configuration screen]

Answer (score 4):

## [Flareget](http://flareget.com)

FlareGet is a full featured, multi-threaded download manager and accelerator for  Linux(Ubuntu/Debian).

**Features**:

- It uses a robust dynamic file segmentation algorithm to speed up the download. The download is split into segments to increase the speed. In addition to dynamic file segmentation, it uses Http-Pipelining which further accelerates each segment.
- It integrates with all the browsers to replace their default download manager and start the download by itself. It supports almost all the browsers – firefox, internet explorer, google chrome, chromium, opera etc.
- It uses an intelligent file management system to automatically categorize your files based on their extensions. All the downloads are grouped in different folders as per their categories.
- It can resume unfinished downloads even on power failures or system crash. It also automatically retries when a segment or download fails. Currently there is no resume support for FTP downloads
- It supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP protocols to let you download files from internet. It also has full Metalink support.
- It supports segmented download of a file from multiple mirror sites with automatic link checking of expired URLs.
- You can limit the download speed to prevent usage of whole bandwidth.
- You can add or remove download segments dynamically without interrupting the download.
- You can limit the number of simultaneous downloads, when one download ends, another starts automatically.
- One click flash video download from Youtube is supported for all the browsers.
- You can easily schedule flareGet to download files automatically. It allows you to start and pause downloading files at the set time.
- No need to copy paste your download links, it monitors your clipboard.
- You can simply import urls from a text file (each link in separate line) or an html file and download them all.
- FlareGet is available in 17 different languages, currently English, Arabic, Farsi, Italian, Chinese(Simplified), French, Czech, Bengali, Spanish, Brazilian Portuguese, Russian, Polski, Turkish, Russian, Nederlands, German and Indonesian are available.
- Both pro and free versions of flareget are available.But free version limit in features as compared to pro version.

  [image]
- In free version,while downloading files which are larger than 25 mb are splitted into 2parts only.But this limitation was not in the pro version

  **Download flareget .deb file from [here](http://flareget.com/download/).**