# Is there any application available to download live streaming videos?

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu.Sometimes I am watching videos tutorials from several sites. Some sites have a download section, some sites are not having a downlod link. I don't want to watch the same tutorial again and again with the help of internet. So I want to download the streaming videos when I watch it the first time, so I will refer the video tutorial next time without internet connection.   I know that Internet Download Manager available for this in Windows OS. But I want know that is there any Linux application available to download all live streaming videos and audios from Website. Does anyone know applications to download streaming videos from video streaming websites?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Could you be a little more specific about how you envision something working for you? The more detail you put into your question, the better and more custom tailored your answers will be. Thanks!

Comment: What video and streaming formats do you want to support? How do you want to decide which videos to support: do you want to point the tool at a streaming video URL, or do you want a tool that also crawls the site? Command line or GUI?

Comment: @Gilles: similar to "Internet Download Manager" in Windows. GUI only.

Comment: “Similar to X” doesn't help if we don't know what it does. When you [ask for alternatives](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software), you can't expect people to know the software that you're using now, especially when you mention software on platform X but are asking users of platform Y.

Comment: There is number of browser extensions for that, would a browser extension satisfy your needs or has to be a desktop software?

Comment: @danijelc If we use browser extension, will it have resume capability, when the internet it cut in mid time ? I feel the desktop application will be better, if it has resume capability.

Comment: reason I'm asking it is cause @Izzy answer would meet all your criteria, including resume but resume doesn’t work well and often you have to restart from zero the download. There would be an work around using web-app and desktop software to meet your requirement.

Comment: @danijelc. Yes Download helper is nice tool. But it does not resume if the download halt in half process. I just asked here to know from geeks that is there any desktop tool available for downloading streaming videos.Now I understand that browser extension is good to get streaming videos. Thank you all

Comment: check comment under @izzy answer, solves all your requirements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you initially already watch the tutorial online, and most likely use *Firefox* to do so, please take a look at **[DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/):**

*DownloadHelper* is a free [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) for downloading and converting videos from many sites with minimum effort. It sits in your toolbar, grayed out ­– and as soon as it detects media (images, audio/video files) if takes on color and gets animated, to inform you there's something to grab. Then you can simply select what you'd like to have. Even streaming videos are detected as soon as they start playing – and hey, you'd either check the quality first before deciding to keep it, right?

**Note:** The plugin was renamed lately to "Video DownloadHelper". That was *after* I installed it. Version number still reflects mine, but of course, I cannot vouch both are the same.

[image: Download-Menu] [image: animated icon]
<sup>Download menu, animated icon (source: [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/))</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Download helper is downloading as well as converting videos.

Comment: Since you asked for resume @balajimca I'll suggest using downloadhelper extension to capture streaming and  than add it to download manager uGet for example which offer excellent acceleration and excellent resume support. Works like a breeze for me.

Comment: @danijelc uGet ?

Comment: check this [answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/download-manager-accelerator-for-debian-ubuntu/1136#1136) for more information on uGet. These two tool (DownloadHelper and  uGet) are my tools to go for recording video streams

Comment: Thanks for this answer @IZZY. Saving lives since 2014

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the protocol used to stream the video. 
At a minimum, you could use a screen capture tool like RecordMyDesktop (easy to find in the Software Center). [This is a good how-to](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24742/record-screen-activity-in-ubuntu-with-recordmydesktop/).

If you are looking for something to specifically capture RTMP (although a lot of streaming sites are moving away from plain RTMP), you could use [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) (might also be available in the Software Center). It can act as a proxy server for your media connections. There are instructions for using it with iptables NAT to make sure that it captures everything ([1](https://askubuntu.com/a/55104/16183), [2](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/use-rtmpsuck-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-t7070.html)), but I have never used it that way.

Comment: how this meet requirements??

Comment: Please don't take this as "bad competition", but a "screen recorder" would miss the sound (not a good thing on tutorials), and "use something like" is not the kind of answers we expect here. We want high quality answers, including details on how they meet the requirements, and best expressing your personal experience with the recommended software. Please see [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details.

Comment: @Izzy RecordMyDesktop also captures sound. As far as "like", that is unfortunately just my writing style.

Comment: @danijelc I answered the question before you edited it. My answer reflects your original question which was "I want know that is there any linux application available to download all live streaming videos and audios from Web browser?". Live streaming and streaming a recorded video are two different operations.

Comment: I haven't done any editing in questions or answers here. @Izzy posted meta where you can see which kind of answers are helpful on this site.

Comment: @danijelc I meant when the asker edited the question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/1421/revisions

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox there are is one I use in combination. First up is [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/), then I do a basic setup and add [Xtreme Download Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/) (there is a Linux version, but I haven't explored Linux all too well). You can easily switch which downloader you want to use.

If you don't want to use an external downloader, you can use FlashGot to set [DownThemAll(DTA)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) as your default downloader. There is also [Turbo Downloader Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/turbo-download-manager/), but IMHO it isn't as powerful as DTA.